# Declaring a pointer to a structure

Tags: c, pointers, struct

What's the difference between

```
struct point var, *varptr;
```

and

```
struct point *var;
```

Can we just use the second one without assigning any variable's address to it?

Comment: You'd have to declare some memory for the pointer and assign the pointer to the address of that memory.

Comment: You cannot dereference either of the pointers without assigning them a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that this statement creates two variables:

```
struct point var, *varptr;
```

It has the same effect as using 2 statements:

```
struct point var; // type struct point
struct point *varptr; // type pointer to struct point
```

And this statement creates 1 variable:

```
struct point *var; // type pointer to struct point
```

> Can we just use the second one without assigning any variable's address to it?

Yes you can use the second one but you would want to initialize it to something (usually another variable's address) before derefrencing the pointer.

Comment: Is it fine to initialise it to a function ?

Comment: If it is a variable declared within a function (aka automatic variable), you can intialize it to the return value from a function that returns type struct point *.  If it is at file scope you can't.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example `var` is a variable with the data type of `struct point` in the memory and `*varptr` is a variable that points to an ADDRESS in the memory with the data type of "struct point".

In the second example `*var` is the same as `*varptr` in the first example. It POINTS to a memory location with the data type of "struct point".